# Лексические ошибки

Tags: лексика

Есть ли лексические ошибки в данном предложении: "Серьёзные дефекты в проведении следующих мероприятий обнаружились только в суде"?

Answer (score 2):

Вы бы все-таки вопрос полностью писали.
Дефект - недостаток материальный. Дырка там в изделии, трещина, непрокрас, недоклей... У ПРОВЕДЕНИЯ (мероприятий) могут быть в лучшем случае недочеты или недоработки.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с behemothus, что в проведении чего-то.... могут быть недочёты, упущения... "Серьёзные дефекты в проведении следующих мероприятий обнаружились только в суде". Я думаю, что речевая  ошибка связана с неудачным, неуместным употреблением заимствованного слова "дефект".
Дефект - от лат. defectus, от deficere - недоставать. (Источник: "Полный словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русском языке").